# Trouble getting started with d and dmd?

Tags: macos, d

I'm just trying out D and rdmd on mac OSX 10.7.5.  I can get "hello world" to compile and run if I don't use rdmd, but I haven't been able to get rdmd to work.  Here are the relevant files:

```
Users-MacBook:DProjects user$ ls -l /usr/bin/rdmd
-rwxr--r--  1 user  staff  27391 May 26 13:53 /usr/bin/rdmd

Users-MacBook:DProjects user$ ls -l ./hello2.d
-rwxr--r--  1 user  staff  78 May 26 14:13 ./hello2.d
```

Here is the program code:
Users-MacBook:DProjects user$ cat hello2.d

```
#!/usr/bin/rdmd
import std.stdio;
void main() {
writeln("Hello, world!");
}
```

When I try to run it -- Users-MacBook:DProjects user$ ./hello2.d

```
./hello2.d: line 2: import: command not found
./hello2.d: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello2.d: line 3: `void main() {'
```

It appears that rdmd runs, but doesn't interpret the code correctly.

Please, can you tell em what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does `which rdmd` output?
And what does `rdmd` output when run? Also try `rdmd hello2.d`, does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like rdmd is running. rdmd wouldn't call `import` a command. That looks like an error from the shell.

Source and permissions for hello2.d look fine, but the file size is off. In UTF8/ASCII, with \n newlines, and without a trailing newline, that should be 75 bytes. 3 extra bytes suggests a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), which would interfere with the requirement that the shebang (`#!`) has to be at the very beginning of the file. Try saving as UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at it in a hex editor and it doesn't start with a BOM.  Also, I substituted a phony name for rdmd and got the message:/usr/bin/srdmd: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.